# Inline evaluation different from non-inline

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

What makes compiler return different results for these two mapped types:

```
type NonNullableObj1<O> = {[Key in keyof O] : O[Key] extends null ? never : O[Key]}

type NotNull<T> = T extends null  ? never : T;
type NonNullableObj2<T> = {[P in keyof T]: NotNull<T[P]>}

type Nullable = {prop: string | null};

type ResultOf1 = NonNullableObj1<Nullable>; // { prop: string | null }
type ResultOf2 = NonNullableObj2<Nullable>; // { prop: string }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOxgVwDaoIYCNUQPJYBWAjADx4B8UAvFAN4DaA0hCFAJYJQDWrcAZlDwBdKAC4hzVqIgAPYBAQATAM5QEaVFAD86iADcIAJ3GSWIYQF8AUNdCRYcYCnSkAKlVpuochcrUa6FA6eoYmEm4A3Hbg0PBImti4BIQATO6e9AwAChxcvCACUG7CEvDOmu45whQ2MQ4umDjQtHRgRnBgEirARpwA5lAAPuqaltH10ABKECpowHj8xDSOCehJ%20ERkjRsU0fbTs-OLqSvxO80p6Re4e0A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both types return different results because of [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

In `NotNull`, `T` is a *naked* generic type on the left side of a condtional. If a union is passed for `T`, each member of this union will be *distributed* over the conditional. So `string` and `null` will be evaluated seperately. Only `string` does **not** extend `null`, so the type evaluates to just `string`.

In `NonNullableObj1`, `O[Key]` is **not** a *naked* generic type because of the indexed access. Therefore, no distribution takes place and the whole union `string | null` is evaluated in the conditional at once. Since `string | null` does **not** extend `null`, it resolves in the false-branch to `O[Key]` which is `string | null`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! So basically there's no way to achieve what `NonNullableObj2` does without a separate conditional type?

Comment: @Tomek - You can. [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WKRQDm) is how that would look like.